# Zlib fails to decompress utf8 encoded string

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, gzip, zlib

I am playing with `zlib` in NodeJs with the following code.

```
const input = 'This is test'
const encoding = 'base64'
zlib.gzip(input, (err, buffer) => {
  if (!err) {
    const stringified = buffer.toString(encoding)
    console.log(stringified)
    const bufferToDeCompress = Buffer.from(stringified, encoding)
    zlib.unzip(bufferToDeCompress, (err, unzippedBuffer) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(unzippedBuffer.toString())
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

So, I am trying to compress and decompress a string. Above code works for all encoding's except for `utf8`. If I change to `utf8`. It throws the following error.

```
{ Error: incorrect header check at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] 
(zlib.js:153:17) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

Anyone came across this?

Comment: I don't get any errors: https://repl.it/repls/NiceRoyalTrace